# Ancestor violates the following Content Security for spotify

Tags: javascript, spotify

Basically I am trying to javascript to add spotify iframes to my html but i keep getting this error and get this error for every link

```
*Refused to display 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5yc5YwQjqcNvGiFsTM0aAT' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".*
```

Then i added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="child-src https://open.spotify.com/">
```

to the header but still no luck

```
    var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
     function getSpotify(artist){
    var spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
        clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        redirectUri: 'http://www.example.com/callback'
    });
    spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
    accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });
    const spotifyDiv = document.createElement("div")
    const result = document.getElementById("result");
    spotifyDiv.className="spotify";
    spotify.searchAlbums(`artist:${artist}`).then(
        (data)=> {
            console.log(data.body)
         data.body.albums.items.forEach((album) =>{
             const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
             iframe.src=album.external_urls.spotify;
             iframe.height = 300;
             iframe.width =300;
             iframe.frameBorder =0;
             iframe.setAttribute("allowtransparency","true");
             iframe.setAttribute("allow","encrypted-media");
             spotifyDiv.appendChild(iframe)
             console.log(iframe)

          });


        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);

        })
    result.appendChild(spotifyDiv)

}
```

Comment: That is for the site you are wanting to display to set not you.

Comment: but it works when i add the html iframe link manually though

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Spotify Web-API: `Refused to display [playlist_link] in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'". #1052` [Link to Spotify Issue](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/1052)

The issue is closed and a possible solution is to ensure your URL has the `/embed/` prefix in the path name.

For example

```
https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/0ODLCdHBFVvKwJGeSfd1jy
```

vs

```
https://open.spotify.com/album/0ODLCdHBFVvKwJGeSfd1jy
```

Comment: Because links can sometimes end up no longer working in the future, it's best to either quote or paraphrase what is said on the external site, even if you do include the link. That way, if the link no longer works in the future, your answer can still be helpful to others with the same question.